# Question list not positioning in the natural flow of App

Tags: html, css, ionic4

Im making a question list for a program that im working on in ionic 4, i made some custom boxes to contain the question and the answers, and that is working properly, responsive and all. But, when i add a second question, the box overlap each other, and i dont know why.

i have tried placing some custom classes with position relative and absolute, but its not working at all.

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
<ion-col size="12">
<div boxCuestionario>
  <div boxPregunta topper>
    <p preguntaText>Q1</p>
  </div>
 <ion-list listCustom>
 <ion-radio-group>
   <ion-item itemCustom>
     <p respuestaText>Ans1</p>
     <ion-radio slot="start" value="biff" checked></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item itemCustom>
    <p respuestaText>Ans2</p>
    <ion-radio slot="start" value="griff"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item itemCustom>
    <p respuestaText>Ans3</p>
    <ion-radio slot="start" value="buford"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-radio-group>
 </ion-list>                
 </div>
 </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
<ion-row>
<ion-col size="12">
<div boxCuestionario>
  <div boxPregunta topper>
    <p preguntaText>Q1</p>
  </div>
 <ion-list listCustom>
 <ion-radio-group>
   <ion-item itemCustom>
     <p respuestaText>Ans1</p>
     <ion-radio slot="start" value="biff" checked></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item itemCustom>
    <p respuestaText>Ans2</p>
    <ion-radio slot="start" value="griff"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item itemCustom >
    <p respuestaText>Ans3</p>
    <ion-radio slot="start" value="buford"></ion-radio>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-radio-group>
 </ion-list>                
 </div>
 </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

I dont know why everytime i put 2 or more rows it get overlaped.

this is the css of the boxes, BoxCuestionario, is the container of all, and boxPregunta is the container of the question:

```
[boxCuestionario]{
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
[boxPregunta]{
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

The other classes are no need (example the text classes) becouse its is just font size and stuff like that.

This is a picture of it, 1 question.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjdzc.jpg

And this is the problem, with 2 or more question, it stacked.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bq1z.jpg